# How to open any other page in Experience editor for FXM

Tags: fxm

I'm using Sitecore 10.2.
Configured an external website. When clicked on `Open in Experience Editor`, it opens the home page of the ext. site. How to open any other page.

Answer (score 1):

FXM will default open the domain URL you set in the website domain field. But once the external website's home page opens you can navigate using any link in the header, footer, or page to your required page. if your page does not have a navigation link to reach, then you can pass the `sc_fxm_url` query string in the URL. for example your external website domain is `extabc.com` and you want to navigate on `https://extabc.com/xyz/pqr` then you can pass `&sc_fxm_url=https://extabc.com/xyz/pqr` in your URL. your final URL will look like this -

```
https://yourscdomain/?sc_mode=edit&sc_lang=en&sc_itemid=%7bC9E357ED-5E80-4CA2-8547-15BEF1B7E370%7d&sc_fxm_url=https://extabc.com/xyz/pqr
```